# Usage of SVG vs font icons in web-development

Tags: html, css, svg, icons, font-awesome

What are the benefits of using SVG over font icons?

I don't care about old browsers. Is it worth to switch to SVG?

Comment: SVG is not easy to sprite. The advantage is SVG will scale to any size without much Browser horse power.

Comment: What have you found out yourself so far? There's plenty of articles and blogs that go into great detail about all imaginable pros and cons.

Comment: @RoelN nothing useful, that's why I'm asking the question in the first place.

Comment: I think this would be a useful question to have here, if its been answered that should be marked

Answer (score 1):

i set myself a guideline when to use SVG when not, simply with >> SVG you can have the vector with colourful elements in it. with font icons, the colour is flat for single vector (which adjust through css color). Font icon has smaller size compare to the svg(XML) since it is compiled.